# Lazy для this.props.children

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Подскажите, есть ли вариант использовать `this.props.children` с lazy эффектом?

Хочу написать компонент-обертку `PropsValidator`, которая в качестве children принимает в себя другие компоненты, использующие props которые еще могут не существовать.
Логику валидации этих props хотел вынести как раз в `PropsValidator`.
Но столкнулся с тем, что this.props.children вычисляются нетерпеливо (eager), из-за чего все крашится (т.к. они стучатся к пропертям которые еще не существуют.)

```js
class PropsValidator extends PureComponent {

  static propTypes = {
    isValid: PropTypes.bool
  }

  static defaultProps = {
    isValid: false
  }

  render() {
    if (this.props.isValid) {
      return <UIActivityIndicator color={colorAccent} />
    } else {
      return this.props.children;
    }
  }
}
```

Использовать планировал так, но т.к. this.props.action.description еще не существует, а this.props.children не ленивые, то происходит краш:

```js
        <PropsValidator isValid={this.props.action && this.props.action.description}>
          <Text>
            {this.props.action.description}
          </Text>
        </LoadableView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Как я понимаю, в обычном варианте ленивые вычисления не реализовать, но можно возложить эту функциональность на Babel. Как, скажем, это делает плагин [jsx-control-statements](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-jsx-control-statements). Ваш пример можно переписать таким способом.

```
<Choose>
  <When condition={this.props.action && this.props.action.description}>
    <Text>{this.props.action.description}</Text>
  </When>
  <Otherwise>
     <UIActivityIndicator color={colorAccent} />
  </Otherwise>
</Choose>
```

Очевидно, подобные конструкции имеют смысл, если только такая разметка уже вложена в какой-нибудь другой элемент. Ведь иначе можно воспользоваться простым `if ... else`.